# Need help in adding rollno and studentname into attendance table

Tags: php, mysql, system

```
<form name="reg" id="reg" method="post" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>">
              <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" style="text-align:left;">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th width="117" height="39" bgcolor="#FFE1CC">Student RollNo</th>
                    <th bgcolor="#FFE1CC">Student Name</th>
                    <th width="100" bgcolor="#ECFAFF">Old Status</th>
                    <th width="1" bgcolor="#FFE1CC">Present</th>
                    <th width="1" bgcolor="#FFE1CC">Absent</th>
                    <th width="1" bgcolor="#FFE1CC">Leave</th>
                    <th width="1" bgcolor="#FFE1CC">Holiday</th>
                  </tr>
                  <?php
                             while ($students = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                          ?>
                  <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#EAFAFF" class="table1"><?php $id = $students['memberid']; ?><?php echo $_POST['department']; ?>-<?php echo $students['rollno']; ?></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#EAFAFF" class="table1"><?php echo $students['fullname']; ?></td>
                    <td align="center" bgcolor="#ECFAFF" class="table1"><?php echo $students['current']; ?></td>
                    <td width="1" align="center" bgcolor="#FFE2D5" id="present"><input type="radio" name="present[<?php echo $students['memberid']; ?>]" value="Present" /></td>
                    <td width="1" align="center" bgcolor="#FFE2D5" id="absent"><input type="radio" name="present[<?php echo $students['memberid']; ?>]" value="Absent" /></td>
                    <td width="1" align="center" bgcolor="#FFE2D5" id="leave"><input type="radio" name="present[<?php echo $students['memberid']; ?>]" value="Leave" /></td>
                    <td width="1" align="center" bgcolor="#FFE2D5" id="holiday"><input type="radio" name="present[<?php echo $students['memberid']; ?>]" value="Holiday" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <input name="fullname" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $students['fullname']; ?>">
                  <input name="rollno" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $students['rollno']; ?>">
                  <input name="percent" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $students['percent']; ?>">
                  <input name="department" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['department']; ?>">
                  <input name="semester" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['semester']; ?>">
                  <input name="session" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['sessionfrom']; ?>-<?php echo $_REQUEST['sessionto']; ?>">
                  <input name="subject" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['subject']; ?>">
                  <input name="date" type="hidden" value="<?php echo date("m-d-Y"); ?>">
                  <?php
                    }
                  ?>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="6" style="vertical-align:middle; text-align: center;"><br />
                      <input id="Submit" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" style="text-align: center; background-color: #000000; color: #ffffff; border: 1px #000000 solid;" /></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="reg" />
            </form>
            <?php
                    if (($_POST["MM_insert"] == "reg")){
                       foreach($_POST['present'] as $student_id => $value) {

                          $sql = "UPDATE members SET current = '".$value."' WHERE memberid = '".$student_id."' ";
                          $result = mysql_query($sql);

                          $sql1 = "INSERT INTO student_attendance (department, semester, session, subject, current, percent, date) VALUES ('".$_REQUEST['department']."','".$_REQUEST['semester']."','".$_REQUEST['session']."','".$_REQUEST['subject']."','$value','".$_REQUEST['percent']."','".$_REQUEST['date']."')";
                          $result = mysql_query($sql1);
                       }
                       header("Location: attendance.php");
                    }


?>
```

Hello Above is my code, everything seem to be working fine. List of students with name, rollno appears as well from members table, and when submit, the status of students of present to either absent or present working fine, it goes well into attendance_record individual, example submitted record of 20 students, 20 rows added with different present status however student name and rollno is coming to be Null.... I have removed the rollno and studentname currently because of only first student name is repeating 20 time and rollno as well.

```
 <?php
                if (($_POST["MM_insert"] == "reg")){
                   foreach($_POST['present'] as $student_id => $value) {

                      $sql = "UPDATE members SET current = '".$value."' WHERE memberid = '".$student_id."' ";
                      $result = mysql_query($sql);

                      $sql1 = "INSERT INTO student_attendance (department, semester, session, subject, current, percent, date) VALUES ('".$_REQUEST['department']."','".$_REQUEST['semester']."','".$_REQUEST['session']."','".$_REQUEST['subject']."','$value','".$_REQUEST['percent']."','".$_REQUEST['date']."')";
                      $result = mysql_query($sql1);
                   }
                   header("Location: attendance.php");
                }


?>
```

Kindly help me correcting it, i cannot use foreach function with more values can you tell how to use while or for for below code, so all student names, rolls including status get submit to attendance_view table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you need more than one value for a particular form field, u need to set date type of form field name as an array
So you need to have name in the input hidden field as **fullname[]** instead of **fullname** 
This will store all of your values in the form and it will not be overwritten.

If u want to store that particular student's full name, then you can set your hidden field like this -

```
<input name="fullname[<?php echo $students['memberid']; ?>]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $students['fullname']; ?>">
```

This should be done for the other hidden fields too.

Comment: Thanks for that,  can you tell full changes, as i added above thing you said however in database instead of values it is showing "Array" ?

Comment: While inserting into database, in the foreach loop of present, you have student_id as key, so u can access value of fullname using $_POST['fullname'.$student_id] and insert it into the database.

Comment: where to add it, not working $_POST['fullname'.$student_id], i added it into insert query where fullname is, also tried it in hidden field, it is passing empty value in database

Comment: can u post your code snippet which is inserting full name to database?

Comment: code is big so posted complete including form, check at http://rayice.com/code.txt

Comment: remember currently sending empty value to database

Comment: Use $_POST['fullname'][$student_id];

Comment: Wow you are Expert! Thank you for helping man it is working like charme, thanks for great solution